# android ui - how to implement a series of dialogs

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

I have the following flow in my application and dont know how to implement this in an android way.

The user can check in the app if there is a update available, if so he can choose if he wants to download it, and once it is downloaded an update of the database takes place.

In the android documentation I only find basic description of either a progress dialog, or alert dialog but not how to have something more complex. For the sake of the example what i would like is the following.

1. The user clicks the check for update button
2. A progress dialog with checking for update pops up (which can be canceled)
3. If there is no update available the user gets informed and can click ok.
4. If there is an update available the user can choose to download it or cancel.
5. If he chooses to download he sees a progress bar. (with a cancel button)
6. Once the download is finished he sees a database updating alert dialog.
7. Finally he gets an all is done info and can click ok

Just an example yet what is the android way of implementing a series of dialogs like this. Wizard, series of different dialogs, one always changing one ...

Suggestion how to implement this in a recommended way would be highly appreciated

thanks

martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each dialog can launch the next subsequent dialog and automatically dismiss itself. Look at the DialogListeners attached to each button in example code

Comment: Thanks CQM - I understand that this would be one way to go yet the reason I am hesitating to do it this way is from a ui design point of view, always changing dialogs with different sizes feel a bit nervous to me - so my question is if there is another way to handle this kind of user interaction in the android world. It feels like a wizard thing yet android doesnt seem to have this in its core

Comment: I also see in some application that they use different activities for each step to have some kind of a wizard look and feel. It works yet I am really interested learning recommended ways of implementing standard tasks as this seems one of the big drawbacks of android application in opposite to iphone apps as in android everybody just does what he feels is nice personally.

Comment: My answer is based on how to implement your original question, but it seems like you are really looking for a better way to display subsequent information?

Comment: Thanks CQM,  that is what I had indeed most likely in the back of my mind, sorry for asking not clearly. Nevertheless as no other approach came up I decided just to go along with using subsequent dialogs and seeing it at work I am quite happy with it. So I ended up implementing what you also suggested, thanks for your replies.

Comment: sorry but I still hope to get another solution as I didnt really ask for a multi dialog solution for which you gave the answer